# Javascript function for array

Tags: javascript, php

I have a poll system. People can vote and choose between two images. I'm trying that if you click 1 image, the other image will change opacity. With my code below only the first match is working. The rest won't change opacity.

```
        echo "<form method='post' action = 'gestemd-test.php?ronde=".$botb_ronde."&mid=".$member_id."&token=".$token."'>";
            $teller = 1;
                while ($aRecord1 = mysql_fetch_array($nummer1) AND $aRecord2 = mysql_fetch_array($nummer2)) {
                    echo "<input type='hidden' name='id_wedstrijd".$teller."' value='".$aRecord1['id_wedstrijd']."'>";
                    echo "<label id='image1' for='thing1".$teller."'><img src='http://kloep.nl/nix/BOTB/2015/deelneemsters/deelneemsters/".$aRecord1['id_deelneemster'].".png' /></label> <input onkeydown='return keyDown(event);' type='radio' name='wedstrijd".$teller."' value='".$aRecord1['id_deelneemster']."' id='thing1".$teller."'>";
                    echo " VS ";
                    echo "<input onkeydown='return keyDown(event);' type='radio' name='wedstrijd".$teller."' value='".$aRecord2['id_deelneemster']."' id='thing2".$teller."'> <label id='image2' for='thing2".$teller."'><img src='http://kloep.nl/nix/BOTB/2015/deelneemsters/deelneemsters/".$aRecord2['id_deelneemster'].".png' /></label><br />";
                    $teller++;
                }
                $teller--;

                echo "<input type='hidden' name='aantal' value='".$teller."'>";
                echo "<input type='hidden' name='naam' value='".$naam."'>";
                echo "<input type='submit' value='Stem!'>";
            echo "</form>";
```

Below is my Javascript function. I put this between the HEAD tags.

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function() {
            var image1 = document.getElementById('image1');
            var image2 = document.getElementById('image2');
                image1.onclick=function(){reset();image2.style.opacity = "0.2";}
                image2.onclick=function(){reset();image1.style.opacity = "0.2";}
        }
        function reset(){
            var image1 = document.getElementById('image1');
            var image2 = document.getElementById('image2');
            image1.style.opacity="1.0";image2.style.opacity="1.0";
        }
    </script>
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: since you are building your html in a `while()` loop, you have multiple `id='image1`/`id='image1`. `id`s are supposed to be UNIQUE. You need to use `class` or other attribute.

Comment: The element with the `id` you search for is a `label`, not an `img`.  Shouldn't you have `id='image1'` in the `<img>` tag instead?

Comment: The issue is clearly the duplicate ID's, `getElementById` will stop looking once a match is found, which is why it only works for the element with that ID.

Comment: The problem was indeed the ID's. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have unique id's for each image. When writing your `<label>` tags for each pair of images, set them up like this:

```
echo "<label id='image1_".$teller."' onclick='fade(1,".$teller.")' for='thing1".$teller."'>
echo "<label id='image2_".$teller."' onclick='fade(2,".$teller.")' for='thing1".$teller."'>
```

Then have a `fade` function in `JavaScript` like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // num is 1 if image1 was clicked, or 2 if image2 was clicked
    // i is the index of the pair being selected (1 through however many pairs)
    function fade(num,i) {
        document.getElementById('image1_'+i).style.opacity = (num==1?"1.0":"0.2");
        document.getElementById('image2_'+i).style.opacity = (num==2?"1.0":"0.2");
    }
</script>
```

The `html` produced by your script will look like this:

```
<label id='image1_1' onclick='fade(1,1)' for='thing11'>
<label id='image2_1' onclick='fade(2,1)' for='thing11'>
<label id='image1_2' onclick='fade(1,2)' for='thing12'>
<label id='image2_2' onclick='fade(2,2)' for='thing12'>
<label id='image1_3' onclick='fade(1,3)' for='thing13'>
<label id='image2_3' onclick='fade(2,3)' for='thing13'>
//... etc for however many pairs
```

The fade method will find exactly the one it's supposed to and set the opacity as you desire and there is no ambiguity as to which image is being adjusted.

**Note:** you don't need the `window.onload` function at all.